# Facing Jfrog issue in android studio

Tags: android, artifactory

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.

getting this error. I have replaced jcenter() by mavenCentral(). Still not working.

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace? Build from command line with `—stacktrace` flag

Comment: I think jcenter() should be kept also, since JCenter will be available read-only repository. Also maybe try adding this: apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

Comment: This plug-in has a latest release of over 2 years ago perhaps you can use instead: org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:version

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel Here is the error stack trace....

Comment: > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :